# I haven't been able to apply the available fix

Tags: react-native, security, npm, dependencies

normalize-url  <=4.5.0 || 5.0.0 - 5.3.0 || 6.0.0
Severity: high
Regular Expression Denial of Service - https://npmjs.com/advisories/1755
fix available via `npm audit fix`
node_modules/normalize-url
compare-urls  <=2.0.0
Depends on vulnerable versions of normalize-url
node_modules/compare-urls
expo-web-browser  >=8.2.0-alpha.1
Depends on vulnerable versions of compare-urls
node_modules/expo-web-browser
expo  >=14.0.0
Depends on vulnerable versions of expo-web-browser
Depends on vulnerable versions of fbemitter
node_modules/expo

Above is an extract of the below.

$ npm install
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/topo@3.1.6: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/bourne@1.3.2: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated text-encoding@0.6.4: no longer maintained
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/address@2.1.4: Moved to 'npm install @sideway/address'
npm WARN deprecated debug@4.1.1: Debug versions >=3.2.0 <3.2.7 || >=4 <4.3.1 have a low-severity ReDos regression when used in a Node.js environment. It is recommended you upgrade to 3.2.7 or 4.3.1. (https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/issues/797)
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/hoek@8.5.1: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated uglify-es@3.3.9: support for ECMAScript is superseded by `uglify-js` as of v3.13.0
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/joi@15.1.1: Switch to 'npm install joi'
npm WARN deprecated core-js@1.2.7: core-js@<3.3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.12: core-js@<3.3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.12: core-js@<3.3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.12: core-js@<3.3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.

added 778 packages, and audited 779 packages in 56s

13 packages are looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details

20 vulnerabilities (16 low, 4 high)

To address issues that do not require attention, run:
npm audit fix

Some issues need review, and may require choosing
a different dependency.

Run `npm audit` for details.

User@DESKTOP-MTV90GM MINGW64 ~/Desktop/[new-game] (master)
$ npm audit fix --force
npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.
npm WARN audit No fix available for react-native@<=0.0.0-81bdeade5 || 0.22.0-rc - 0.63.4
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN Found: expo@37.0.12
npm WARN node_modules/expo
npm WARN   expo@"^37.0.0" from the root project
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer expo@"^32.0.0" from expo-graphics-rnge@1.2.0
npm WARN node_modules/expo-graphics-rnge
npm WARN   expo-graphics-rnge@"^1.2.0" from the root project
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN Found: expo-gl@8.1.0
npm WARN node_modules/expo-gl
npm WARN   expo-gl@"~8.1.0" from the root project
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer expo-gl@"^4.0.0" from expo-graphics-rnge@1.2.0
npm WARN node_modules/expo-graphics-rnge
npm WARN   expo-graphics-rnge@"^1.2.0" from the root project

added 16 packages, and audited 795 packages in 22s

13 packages are looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details

## npm audit report

mem  <4.0.0
Denial of Service - https://npmjs.com/advisories/1084
No fix available
node_modules/mem
os-locale  2.0.0 - 3.0.0
Depends on vulnerable versions of mem
node_modules/os-locale
yargs  4.0.0-alpha1 - 12.0.5 || 14.1.0 || 15.0.0 - 15.2.0
Depends on vulnerable versions of os-locale
Depends on vulnerable versions of yargs-parser
node_modules/logkitty/node_modules/yargs
node_modules/yargs
logkitty  <=0.6.1
Depends on vulnerable versions of yargs
node_modules/logkitty
@react-native-community/cli-platform-android  <=4.9.0
Depends on vulnerable versions of logkitty
node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android
react-native  <=0.0.0-81bdeade5 || 0.22.0-rc - 0.63.4
Depends on vulnerable versions of @react-native-community/cli
Depends on vulnerable versions of @react-native-community/cli-platform-android
Depends on vulnerable versions of fbjs
node_modules/react-native
@react-native-community/cli  *
Depends on vulnerable versions of metro
Depends on vulnerable versions of react-native
node_modules/@react-native-community/cli
metro  0.22.1 - 0.63.0
Depends on vulnerable versions of fbjs
Depends on vulnerable versions of metro-config
Depends on vulnerable versions of metro-inspector-proxy
Depends on vulnerable versions of yargs
node_modules/metro
metro-config  <=0.57.0
Depends on vulnerable versions of metro
node_modules/metro-config
metro-inspector-proxy  0.53.0 - 0.57.0
Depends on vulnerable versions of yargs
node_modules/metro-inspector-proxy

node-fetch  <=2.6.0 || 3.0.0-beta.1 - 3.0.0-beta.8
Denial of Service - https://npmjs.com/advisories/1556
No fix available
node_modules/node-fetch
isomorphic-fetch  2.0.0 - 2.2.1
Depends on vulnerable versions of node-fetch
node_modules/isomorphic-fetch
fbjs  0.7.0 - 1.0.0
Depends on vulnerable versions of isomorphic-fetch
node_modules/fbemitter/node_modules/fbjs
node_modules/fbjs
expo-font  8.1.1 - 8.4.0
Depends on vulnerable versions of fbjs
node_modules/expo-font
fbemitter  2.0.3 - 3.0.0-alpha.1
Depends on vulnerable versions of fbjs
node_modules/fbemitter
expo  >=14.0.0
Depends on vulnerable versions of expo-web-browser
Depends on vulnerable versions of fbemitter
node_modules/expo
metro  0.22.1 - 0.63.0
Depends on vulnerable versions of fbjs
Depends on vulnerable versions of metro-config
Depends on vulnerable versions of metro-inspector-proxy
Depends on vulnerable versions of yargs
node_modules/metro
@react-native-community/cli  *
Depends on vulnerable versions of metro
Depends on vulnerable versions of react-native
node_modules/@react-native-community/cli
react-native  <=0.0.0-81bdeade5 || 0.22.0-rc - 0.63.4
Depends on vulnerable versions of @react-native-community/cli
Depends on vulnerable versions of @react-native-community/cli-platform-android
Depends on vulnerable versions of fbjs
node_modules/react-native
metro-config  <=0.57.0
Depends on vulnerable versions of metro
node_modules/metro-config

normalize-url  <=4.5.0 || 5.0.0 - 5.3.0 || 6.0.0
Severity: high
Regular Expression Denial of Service - httpsnpmjscomadvisories1755
fix available via `npm audit fix`
node_modules/normalize-url
compare-urls  <=2.0.0
Depends on vulnerable versions of normalize-url
node_modules/compare-urls
expo-web-browser  >=8.2.0-alpha.1
Depends on vulnerable versions of compare-urls
node_modules/expo-web-browser
expo  >=14.0.0
Depends on vulnerable versions of expo-web-browser
Depends on vulnerable versions of fbemitter
node_modules/expo

yargs-parser  <=13.1.1 || 14.0.0 - 15.0.0 || 16.0.0 - 18.1.1
Prototype Pollution - https://npmjs.com/advisories/1500
No fix available
node_modules/logkitty/node_modules/yargs-parser
node_modules/yargs-parser
yargs  4.0.0-alpha1 - 12.0.5 || 14.1.0 || 15.0.0 - 15.2.0
Depends on vulnerable versions of os-locale
Depends on vulnerable versions of yargs-parser
node_modules/logkitty/node_modules/yargs
node_modules/yargs
logkitty  <=0.6.1
Depends on vulnerable versions of yargs
node_modules/logkitty
@react-native-community/cli-platform-android  <=4.9.0
Depends on vulnerable versions of logkitty
node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android
react-native  <=0.0.0-81bdeade5 || 0.22.0-rc - 0.63.4
Depends on vulnerable versions of @react-native-community/cli
Depends on vulnerable versions of @react-native-community/cli-platform-android
Depends on vulnerable versions of fbjs
node_modules/react-native
@react-native-community/cli  *
Depends on vulnerable versions of metro
Depends on vulnerable versions of react-native
node_modules/@react-native-community/cli
metro  0.22.1 - 0.63.0
Depends on vulnerable versions of fbjs
Depends on vulnerable versions of metro-config
Depends on vulnerable versions of metro-inspector-proxy
Depends on vulnerable versions of yargs
node_modules/metro
metro-config  <=0.57.0
Depends on vulnerable versions of metro
node_modules/metro-config
metro-inspector-proxy  0.53.0 - 0.57.0
Depends on vulnerable versions of yargs
node_modules/metro-inspector-proxy

20 vulnerabilities (16 low, 4 high)

To address issues that do not require attention, run:
npm audit fix

Some issues need review, and may require choosing
a different dependency.

Comment: node version is 14.17.1
npm version is 7.18.1

Comment: I ran npm i yargs-parser --save